# shared CSS and JS multiples projects Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, npm, asp.net-core

I have a project which will have a framework for several projects, these projects will be done in asp.net core, several CSS files and JavaScripts will be shared between the projects, I would not like to copy and paste these files in each project, I would like to know how to share these CSS and JavaScript files in multiple projects?

Currently the project uses NPM for the libs, having to download the same ones in each of the projects, this would have like to centralize also?

Note: the project will be large, I would like to facilitate the maintenance in these files JS and CSS, thus changing in a single file and these changes change in all projects that use the same.

Comment: You can host those files in a separate website and use absolute urls in your other projects in to include them ( similar to hosted cdn jQuery link)

Comment: you can package them as embedded resources in a class library shared as a NuGet package and you can serve them either using StaticFilesMiddleware with EmbeddedFileProvider or using a controller in the class library. That is what I do in my projects.

Comment: It might be silly but u can use symbolic link in NTFS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)

Comment: Voted for close for "primarily opinion-based" question, you might get ideas but not a "solution". Mine is: You probably use Grunt or Gulp for possible bunding, minification, extracting the dist files out of the Bower and NPM Modules etc... (let's call it "source") So we have one projects which takes care of all this source css/js (it contains the gulpfile...), and it copies the prepared files around to all other "target" projects which require those files.

Comment: I need to also share controller and views, the framework being created will have to reuse for example, error views, login views. I searched several times on the internet, all the implementations I tested did not succeed. Does anyone know how to share, CSS, JS, View and Controller?